# How to check if a ZF2 view template exists?

Tags: zend-framework2

I know how to set a specific template for the ViewModel. But how would I check if a different template actually exists in the current template path stack before setting the template in the ViewModel? The idea being that I can reuse a single action to render views based on a query parameter. I want to check first so if the view doesn't exists then I can set the response status code to a 404 instead of the generic server error message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can do the following, assuming you want to do it from a controller

```
    $template = 'non/existant/template';
    $resolver = $this->getEvent()
        ->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager()
        ->get('Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack');

    if (false === $resolver->resolve($template)) {

        // does not exist
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check a view exists from another view ( perhaps you are loading a partial ) you can use

```
<?php if ($this->resolver('layouts/default')) : ?>
    <?php $this->render('layouts/default'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Test that a view exists in ZF2](http://richardjh.org/blog/test-that-a-view-exists-in-zf2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ZF2Twig it should be:

```
$template = "non/existant/twig-template";
/** @var \ZfcTwig\View\TwigResolver $resolver */
$resolver = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ZfcTwig\View\TwigResolver');
if (false === $resolver->resolve($template)) {
    // Twig template does not exist
}
```